# Arch Linux live boot unreadable text

Tags: arch-linux, boot, nvidia, live-usb, graphics

when booting into a fresh arch live usb, the text becomes unreadable (see photo), any way to resolve this issue?

My system:

- AMD Ryzen 7 5700x
- 32GB RAM
- Nvidia RTX 3070
- MSI X570-A Pro

[image]

Comment: Offhand, it looks like video corruption. Either a bad video card/video memory, or a bad/incorrect driver. Can you download something such as FreeDOS (or anything else bootable that is mainly text mode) and see if the problem persists?

Comment: Does the problem go away when you finish booting?

Comment: @terdon I have waited several minutes and nothing happens.

The graphics card is just fine (works perfectly on windows). I will try that with FreeDOS

Comment: Btw FreeDOS was not working at all, I simply could not boot into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to resolve this issue:
I used a dual monitor setup with the main one connected via Displayport and the secondary one via HDMI. Even with only the main one connected I would receive such errors.
But when the system was booted I removed the primary and connected the secondary one and was able to get an image.

I did not try to only use the HDMI at first, but maybe this will also work.